# Why are $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ used in solving this case of Laplace's equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplace-expansion, linear-pde

I'm currently trying to find the separable solution to the PDE
$$
u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0
$$
Subject to the boundary conditions
$$
u(0,y) = u(a,y) = 0
$$

To attempt this, I have expressed $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ which makes the PDE
$$
X''(x)Y(y) + X(x)Y''(y) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow -\frac{X''}{X} = \frac{Y''}{Y} = \lambda \\
\Rightarrow X'' + \lambda X = 0
$$

Solving this, using the boundary conditions gives us that the only non-trivial solution to the ODE is the oscillatory solution
$$
X_n (x) = \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right)
$$
With $\lambda_n = \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{a^2}$.
So far so good. I have the solutions to this question, and this is the same result.

Now comes the confusion...

We now need to find the corresponding solution in terms of $Y$ to obtain the separable solution. I calculated this as
$$
Y_n (y) = A_n \cos \left( \frac{n \pi y}{a} \right) + B_n \sin \left( \frac{n \pi y}{a} \right)
$$
However, I have checked the mark scheme and the solution they have for $Y$ is 
$$
Y_n (y) = A_n \cosh \left( \frac{n \pi y}{a} \right) + B_n \sinh \left( \frac{n \pi y}{a} \right)
$$

I have never seen $cosh$ and $sinh$ used in the general solution to a second order ODE, and have no idea why it is being used here.

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

you use sin and cosine for a differential equation like this

$$ -y''(x)+\lambda y (x) = 0 $$

but your equation is  $$ y''(x)+\lambda y (x) = 0 $$

can you spot the diffente sign in the second derivative ?

Comment: I think you have your differential equations the wrong way round: $-y''(x)+\lambda\,y(x)=0$ yields the hyperbolic basis of solutions and $y''(x)+\lambda\,y(x)=0$ the trigonometric ones.

Comment: What is the rule involving hyperbolic solutions?